# Relationship field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following structure in my models.py document:

```
class Player(Human):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=24)
    jersey_number = models.IntegerField()

class Coach(Human):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=24)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    players = models.SomethinToSomething(Player)
    coaches = models.SomethinToSomething(Coach)
```

I would like in my admin section to create teams and inside each team add some players and some coaches, I want that a player is related only with the team where I created it, so if I'm in team A it has to be impossible for me see and adding player of other team.

I tried OneToOne() but I can link only one player and only one coach to the team.
I tried ManyToMany() but when I make the second team the players of the first team are shared with the first team.

What should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do something like this,

```
class Team(models.Model):
      name = # ..

class Player(models.Model):
      name = # ..
      jer_num = # ...
      team = models.ForeignKey(Team, #..)

class Coach(models.Model):
     name = # ..
     team = models.ForeignKey(Team, #..)
```

When you will add a player or a coach, the team will be added as a choice field. Because, the the teams (mostly) remain same and the players and coaches changes, this will give you flexibility. 
And also if you want to add something like transfer, you can use team in your forms.

Comment: After is possible to see in the admin section for each team its instances of Player and Coach?

Comment: on default admin page, i guess it will not show up. But you can see all players and coaches of single team with simple queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `ForeignKey()` to achieve your desired.

Comment: I've tried it but it's working the same as OneToOne()